# Convert ASP HTTP request to PHP Curl request

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, curl, http-headers

If this code is correct and working in asp

```
String xmlstc = "Some XML Code";
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(server);
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = xmlstc.Length;
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
streamWriter.Write(xmlstc);`
```

I want to achieve the same thing in PHP using curl. Is the following code correct?

```
$xmlrequest = 'some xml code'

$server = ''

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: \"run\"",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($requestXML)
    //"Connection: close",
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXML); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Advice: avoid setting Content-Length as a custom header, libcurl will add its own version of it based on the length of the data you send in the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option and getting it wrong is a common reason for weird behavior.

Comment: Problem Solved. BTW thanks Daniel for sharing your knowledge :)